# How would I copy a part of this int array into another in C++?

Tags: c++

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size;
    int sizeCopy= 0;
    int *array;

    cin >> size;
    cout << endl;
    cin >> sizeCopy;

    array = new int [size];
    int i = 0;
    int counter = 1;

    while(i<size)
    {
        array[i] = counter;
        ++counter;
        ++i;
    }

    cout << "The array contains: ";
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

So far I created a program that will ask for the user input for the size of the array, and the size of how many elements of the array will be copied in the new array (That's sizeCopy).

I managed to create the first array, I wanted it to be like this: If the user input was 3, the array would contain 1, 2, 3.
I the user input was 10 the array would contain 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.

This seems to work perfectly.
Now I would like to copy a part of my int array to another, but it's a bit more complicated than that.
Let's say the user input for the first array (size) is 10, and the sizeCopy (how many elements you want copied into the second array) is 2, then I would want the second array to be: 1, 2.
That's not over though, I want the whole array to be copied into the second array after a while.
I would like something like this:

- 1, 2
- Received part 1
- 1, 2, 3, 4
- Received part 2
- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
- Received part 3
- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
- Received part 4
- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
- Received part 5

With the "Received part .. " included in the program.
And then it would be done.

If the user for the size of the first array would be 4, and the sizeCopy would be 2, then I would want something like this:

- 1, 2
- Received part 1
- 1, 2, 3, 4
- Received part 2

Could I get some help on how to get this done?
I think I could manage how to copy the whole array into the other, or at least a part of it. But how would one do what I'd like to do? I supposed I would need loops, but I don't know more.

Comment: why don't you use std::vector instead?

Comment: I have never used vectors before, would it be that much more simple?

Comment: No they were invented to make things harder

Comment: That should have a `</sarcasm>` attached to it...

Comment: Hey, no need to be a jerk. I just don't know where to start. I've never used them, so a link to teach me how to use them would be nicer.

Comment: Slightly less hash than the last comment - do you have to use Arrays for this (as in homework requirement?)

Comment: @Exn: Your C++ book is the best place to start. If you don't have one: http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources

Comment: @Exn they might appear harder at first, but they are worth learning. Just google `std::vector`, should come right up.

Comment: `std::vector` can be used almost like an array, so it is not so difficult to learn. Then you can go into iterators, which are tougher, but in the end are so much more flexible, and improve your code with them. And you may also want to look at `std::list`, which has a function called `splice()` that does some nice things related with what you want (though not exactly the same).

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr I'm gonna answer the question in the title.

Use `std::vector` with the constructor

```
template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

or [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: +1 for the first sentence mostly

Answer (score -1):

I don't like the C++ way(of std::copy) - i rather use `memcpy()` or `memmove()`. I feel more *in* _control_ `</sarcasm>`

Comment: That should have a `</sarcasm>` attached to it...

Comment: You feel less in control when you are using a function the implementation of which you can read the source code?

Comment: Some of our older code once used `memcpy` on some hand-coded container. One day the container was rightly transformed into an `std::map`, but after that for MONTHS nobody noticed the glaring UB in the `memcpy` because of the C casts and that all the types were just being hacked to hell. Took two people a week to find the cause of a serious memory problem in our production code. Use `std::copy` -- it'll _tell_ you when it no longer works.

Comment: the stupid `</sarcasm>` tag got interpreted as HTML code

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Dennis Ritchie would have flipped in his grave

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit this bug took two people a week? How long did that go on for? You must have lost a lot of team members, I'm sorry for your loss.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: We did :) Colleagues learnt `gdb` that week.

Comment: @Aniket I didn't see your sarcasm tags, so I removed my downvote, but sarcasm should be in comments, not composing entire answers.

Comment: @SethCarnegie is not wrong about that. But I'm in a good mood.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I take my words back then :)